# What will happen if I turn off copy protection?

Tags: android, google-play

I use SQLite DB in my app. Is SQLLite bases will erased if i turn on copy protection in market? (I mean bases in phones of my costumers)
I found both side comments. How it works now?

Comment: Keep in mind that copy protection is deprecated and it will b removed from the market. Look at here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Comment: I know it, but I want turn it off.

Comment: are you asking about turning it on? Or turning it off?